# show/hide div with dyamically assigned class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically assigning the div id based on the api call back data. For example I have a bunch of data returned which is appended to a div and I can assign the div id with a unique ip address. I have full control over what I can assign i.e. DIV id or class or whatever..

I have attached an example of what the output looks like and hopefully it will clarify what i am looking for.

[image]

What I want to be able to achieve is when an endpoint link is clicked, it will show the respective div and hide all other DIV data boxes.. The endpoint links can made clickable and i can add onclick scripts to them or whatever needs to be done

Whether we use the div id or class name i am not fussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work just fine.

Assign your div with a class, in the demo i'm using `EndPoint`. The onclick function will use the class to find the div element and hide it. Then it will use `this` the element used to trigger the function, target the div within that element and show it.

```js
$('.EndPoint').on('click', function () {
    $('.EndPoint').find('div').hide();
    $(this).find('div').show();
});
```

```css
.EndPoint div{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="EndPoint">
  <a href="#">End Point [0]</a>
    <div><b>IP Address:</b> 216.12.145.20</div>
</div>
<div class="EndPoint">
  <a href="#">End Point [1]</a>
    <div><b>IP Address:</b> 172.230.105.123</div>
</div>
<div class="EndPoint">
  <a href="#">End Point [2]</a>
    <div><b>IP Address:</b> 206.204.52.31</div>
</div>
```

If you don't understand anything please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

---

> **Edit** - jQuery Append with onclick

```js
var IPs=["216.12.145.20","172.230.105.123","206.204.52.31"];
//Foreach value in array
$.each(IPs, function(i,v) {
//Append to id:container
$('#container').append('<div class="EndPoint"><a href="#">End Point ['+i+']</a><div><b>IP Address:</b> '+v+'</div></div>');
});
$('.EndPoint').on('click', function () {
    $('.EndPoint').find('div').hide();
    $(this).find('div').show();
});
```

```css
.EndPoint div{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: this appears to function exactly how i want it to but i need some time to work this into my code.. the only comment is the ip address data will be in a div of its own and the div id with be the ip address. The data wont be <p> tags so hopefully that wont be an issue?

Comment: doesn't seem to work if the data is being presented with .append() ?

$response0.append("<div class='Endpoint'><a href='#'><h3>Endpoint ["+i+"]</h3></a><div>test data</div>");

Comment: Capital P in EndPoint. Don't forget to close the first div too.

Comment: Try this `$response0.append("<div class='EndPoint'><a href='#'><h3>Endpoint ["+i+"]</h3></a><div>test data</div></div>");`

Comment: For some reason its not reading the css style.. when i run the output everything is expanded and clicking the endpoint link doesnt do anything.

`<style type="text/css">
   .EndPoint div {
    display:none;
    }
</style>`

Comment: Have you made the changes to your append? `P` is uppercase and css/js is case sensitive and you didn't close the EndPoint div in your append. If this still isn't working can you check your browser console for errors. If no errors are in the console you may need to create a jsfiddle with more of your source code.

Comment: okay, looks like i had the </a> in the wrong place.. okay now the data is displayed and everything is hidden but clicking the endpoint links does not expand..

Comment: yes, i closed the div and capitalized the P.. seems now its not reading the jquery part.. no errors in the console. I added this to my .js file `$('.EndPoint').on('click', function () {
    $('.EndPoint').find('div').hide();
    $(this).find('div').show();
});`

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you this also works when using `append()`. Leave feedback, if you still have trouble with this I will move this conversation into a chat so we can resolve the issue.

Comment: ahh ur a legend! it was the jquery function being in the wrong place! seriously thanks for hanging in there with me. I will gladly mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Since elements are dynamically generated it's better to do with classes IMO.

HTML

```
<div id="endpoint1"> 
    <a href='#' class='clicker'>End Point 1</a>
    <p class='hideThis'>1.1.1.1</p>
</div>
<div id="endpoint2"> 
    <a href='#' class='clicker'>End Point 2</a>
    <p class='hideThis'>1.1.1.1</p>
</div>
<div id="endpoint3"> 
    <a href='#' class='clicker'>End Point 3</a>
    <p class='hideThis'>1.1.1.1</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript (using JQuery)

```
$('.clicker').on('click', function () {
    $('.hideThis').hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ksvexr40/1

If you want to hide the content initially, just add the following CSS class which hides the content initially.

```
.hideThis{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: looks promising but i don't want to hide the endpoint links as i want to be able to click on them as well. I just want to hide the data under it